# Is it possible to send a response and then execute the rest of the cloud function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have an HTTP Firebase Cloud Function written in nodejs where 3rd party applications pushes data which can take very long to finish. For this particular use case, I don't want those 3rd party applications to wait until the function has finished executing and returns 200 response.

Is it possible to send a res.status(200).send() at the beginning of the Cloud Function and then start executing the rest of the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily achieve that with Cloud Functions, but you can with Cloud Run. (In reality, you can hack the thing by using Cloud Functions gen2 and update manually the Cloud Run parameters after the deployment)

First, let me explain the problem: Serverless services are great because you pay only for what you use. And you pay only the CPU and Memory that you use during the request processing, and not when you are not using it.

This processing duration is calculated between the request and the response of your service. When the response is sent, you no longer pay for the resources. Therefore Google throttles the CPU (bellow 5%) to avoid usage outside "billable period".

In that context, you can understand that, if you send the response, and then perform extra processing in the background, you will use throttled CPU and it won't work.

The trick to solve that, is to deactivate the CPU throttling. You can achieve that with [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation#console)

Be careful about the pricing. Because the CPU is not throttled (and shared with other customers) you will pay for it up to the instance offload (15 minutes after the latest response sent)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with pub/sub?

Comment: You can use Eventarc if you want, or you can use a simple PubSub push subscription

Comment: Any  PubSub push subscription example that can be shared?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You just send the response before you call your function.

```
const SERVER = http.createServer(async function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end("Working on it...");
  myFunction();
}
```

Comment: The issue is not in the code, but on the platform.

Comment: Really? Where is that behavior documented? You're saying that Cloud Functions terminates when Node.js sends an HTTP response?

Comment: Not end, but the CPU is throttled.

Comment: Agree, not documented. But you can have a try ;) You have max 5% of CPU allocated. Writing a log could be possible (like maintaining database connection as global variable for instance). But you can hardly perform more!

Comment: I'll try it if someone pays me to ;-)

Comment: So, you can trust me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
As @guillaume blaquiere points out in his answer, the GCP platform would be throttling down the CPU after the response is sent for the reason that was described in the answer. So, the real solution to the problem lies in the platform rather than in the code. But I will still leave my answer here to impress upon the fact that Node.JS can process further even after sending a response to a request.

---

The HTTP Cloud functions should be Express Middleware Functions. This makes it incredibly easy to achieve your goal. Just like how this exact operation could be done in any Node Express application, just send the response at any point you need and continue with your process.

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

// Register an HTTP function with the Functions Framework
functions.http('myHttpFunction', (req, res) => {


  // Send an HTTP response
  res.send('Your request is being handled.');


  // Your code here
  console.log('starting the long process...');
  ...
  ...

});
```

Comment: The issue is not in the code, but on the platform.

Comment: I read your answer. You have a point there. It is a  valid reason for GCP to do what you claim. I will update my answer.@guillaumeblaquiere